# EventListener() keeps the Activity from going to another Activity if data changes

Tags: java, android

After logins back, the user will redirected to ProfileActivity with some EditText etc. pre-filled with the user information and if they are ready, the user clicks Save button. When user decided not to change their details, it goes smoothly to MainActivity. However, if they decided to do otherwise and clicked Save, it goes back to ProfileActivity again.

ProfileActivity.java

```java
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.uname)
    TextInputEditText uname;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_save)
    Button btnSave;

    String id = "";
    DatabaseReference tbUser;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        tbUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");

        initView();
    }

private void initView() {
        id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        tbUser.child(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User item;
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class) != null) {
                    item = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    uname.setText(item.getName());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    @OnClick({R.id.btn_save})
    public void onViewClicked(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_save:
                 if(!uname.getText().toString().isEmpty) {
                     //some code to add user
                     finish();
                 }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post save button coding.

Comment: As I can see, if the textfield is not empty you finish the ProfileActivity, otherwise nothing will happen. can you post the code when the user edit the textview ?

Comment: One thing you can do is to store a flag such as boolean touched = false; You then add a TextWatcher to the edittexts, when any of the edittexts is altered, u set the flag to true and use the value of the flag to either load ProfileActivity or MainActivity